# Change error image in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Cordova and InAppBrowser plugin to see external links in my app(android). But when device doesn't have connection and I am trying to go for external link it shows Android error(see image).

Question:
How to change this standard error page ([standard error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xfli.png)) to my custom error page?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use like this :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
             if(navigator.onLine) {
                  var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
                   ref.show();
                  } else {
                   //create page in folder www like index2.html and include 
                      alert("No Internet Pleas active your internet");
                      window.location = "index2.html";


                  }
        }
```